# How to store check box value ckecked as 1 and unchecked as 0 in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

How to store check box value ckecked as 1 and unchecked as 0 in mysql
My form is this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="skill['+skillcount+'][gdskill]">
 <input type="checkbox" name="skill['+skillcount+'][piskill]">
```

And my controller page:

```
foreach($_POST["skill"] as $k=>$key)
{
$conn->query("INSERT INTO r_job_skill
(id_job,title,weightage,type,gdskill,piskill) values
 ('".$jobId."',
  '".$key["title"]."',
  '".$key["weightage"]."',
  '".$key["type"]."',
  '".$key["gdskill"]."',
  '".$key["piskill"]."')
 ");
}
```

Comment: I have provided you with an option of how to store it onto the DB based on checked status.

Comment: Now check i have updated the answer and now your error will not occur :)

Comment: Note: totally vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at the time of insert into Mysql DB.

`isset()` — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set. isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. Also note that a null character ("\0") is not equivalent to the PHP NULL constant.

If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

```
if(isset($_POST['skill'])) { // where skill is the check box name
   // Here it executes for not checked
   $cval = '0';
} else {
   // Here it executes for checked
   $cval = '1';
}
```

And after that you can insert the `$cval` into the Query for execution purpose.

**Another Method:**

```
if(!isset($_POST['skill'])) { // where skill is the check box name
   $cval = '1';  
} else {
   $cval = '0';
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code: `isset($_POST['skill']=='')` » `isset($_POST['skill'])` // you want to check if the key isset in the array and not the comparison

Comment: @Naresh Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: @CodeBrauer. I have changed the code now as per the comments

Comment: @AbdulWaheed. Now check i have updated the answer.. :)

Comment: `$cval = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'skill', FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);` or `$cval = isset($_POST['skill']);` are shorter (I dislike the 2nd since it access `$_POST` directly)